# Но() как... Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

*"В оригинале пятые «Трансформеры» имеют подзаголовок «Последний рыцарь», но(,) как картину локализуют для российского проката, пока не сообщается."* Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь НО тесно связано по смыслу с союзным словом КАК, поэтому запятой нет.